# Help needed to find 7th & 8th grade completed math samples

Tags: technology-in-education, interactive-teaching, usa, middle-school, resource-request

I am trying to find samples of completed homework, class work and tests for 7th and 8th grade math in the US. I can find a million blank workbooks but not copies that students have completed with shown work, correct answers, incorrect answers etc.

If you know of good resources or have materials of your own with completed assignments I'd love to hear from you!

I'm developing a virtual teacher assistant.
For it to be able to learn it needs thousands of samples to recognize patterns and correctly grade assignments/tests, and over time customize learning strategies for individual students and their learning needs.

Would love any support, feedback, resources. My goal is to build this with teachers for teachers.

Comment: There is a privacy issue here.  Generally students don't consent to this, and their consent (and their parents' consent) would be required.

Comment: Is this a commercial undertaking?

Comment: @JW what do you mean by  commercial? It will be a product developed. My goal isn’t to sell it but release it for use.

Comment: It would be good to edit your post to clarify that.

Answer (score 6):

One way to go is to do this in partnership with a school or a university (or other higher education institute) that does teacher education.

Pupil workbooks are rarely published, and you might face some issues of copyright or ethics if the corpus you find is not explicitly published under a free license.

So: since your goal is to build it with teachers, talk with teachers. Check your local legislation for what kind of ethics/copyright clearance you need, if anything, to gather and analyze pupil data (universities can help with this kind of stuff). Then figure out together with the teachers the logistics of it and get going.

I do admit that it sounds like an ambitious project if you intend to take as input pictures or scans of hand-drawn responses (for example) and want to output useful formative, or even summative, assessment. The program also needs to understand the question and the varied and freeform responses. Maybe some more limited format, like digital responses, are a bit easier to get started with.